# Convert byte array or Bitmap to Picture

Tags: android, bitmapimage, data-conversion

I am trying to convert images to video with jcodec. The function to get images is:

```
public void encodeNativeFrame(Picture pic) throws IOException
```

I can send to this funciton Bitmap or byte array of the same Bitmap coverted to YUV420.

My question is how to convert Bitmap to Picture or convert byte array (byte[]) to Picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to create a bitmap :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(yourByteArray, 0, yourByteArray.length);
```

Then, get a canvas in which you will record =

```
Picture picture = new Picture();
Canvas canvas = picture.beginRecording(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

Then, draw the bitmap on your canvas

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(0f, 0f, (float) bitmap.getWidth, (float) bitmap.getHeight), null);
```

Then, end the record

```
picture.endRecording();
```

Then, the picture will contain your Bitmap.

Here a method doing that :

```
public Picture fromByteArray(byte[] byteArray){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    Picture picture = new Picture();
    Canvas canvas = picture.beginRecording(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(0f, 0f, (float) bitmap.getWidth, (float) bitmap.getHeight), null);
    picture.endRecording();
    return picture;
}
```